# Stripping out all html on java variable

Tags: java, android, html

I have a variable which contains an img tag and then various p tags. I want to remove all of these and be left with just the text. The text has several special characters within, such as `&#8211;` and `&quot;`.

I am trying to convert all of this to just plain text to be displayed in an Android app.

I've tried `Html.escapeHtml` but it just removes the `<img` part and leaves the rest.

Any ideas?

Comment: You were close:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)

is what you probably want.

Comment: I just want to completely remove the img tag and p tags to leave unstyled text only.

Comment: I have not tried this, but you should be able to iterate over the parts of the Spanned returned Spanned.getSpans(int, int, java.lang.Class<T>) and then concatenating only the text contents of all of these...

Comment: Solved by adding .toString at the end of the fromHtml. :)

Comment: That's even better...